# Unknown Column error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add a value in phpMyAdmin database
But it shows an error like thus
**Unknown Column '$sender' in the ' field list '** my programs looks like this:-

```
function send_msg($sender,$message)
    {
   if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message))
    {
        $message  = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
        $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat (sender,message) VALUES ($sender,$message)");
        if($query)
          {
                    print "sent";
            }
      else
      {
            print  "fail  ".mysql_error();
        }
    }
    else
         print "Cant be Empty";
}
```

This program get this output error

> fail Unknown column '$sender' in 'field list'

But if use the single quote in this line

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat (sender,message) VALUES ('$sender' ,'$message')");
```

It print sent and insert the variable **$sender** and **$message** in database not. 
Help me anyone!

Answer (score -1):

You do not have a column with name "sender" in your table.

Edit: I am wrong. It is not sender but $sender. I am running to office will see this from there and edit the answer.

Comment: i am having a table named "sender"

Comment: Column is needed with name sender not the table. Paste `describe chat;` output. Run this on MySQL prompt or MySQLAdmin.

Comment: yeah i am having table name chat and column name id, sender &  message

Comment: and id is having primary and A_I

Comment: Can you please paste the output?

Comment: this is the output (fail Unknown column '$sender' in 'field list')

Comment: No you have not pasted. Please paste the output verbatim along with command.

Comment: what do you mean? i don't understand

Comment: Hey, don't waste tour time to solve this because. I got the solution.

Comment: I am giving the single quote to the parameter in send_msg('$sender', '$message')

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat (sender,message) VALUES ('".$sender."' ,'".$message."')");
```